# Circle Equation Surjectivity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, circles, inverse

> Consider the circular function $g:\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{+}$, $g(x,y)=x^{2}+y^{2}$. Show that it is surjective and continuous.

**Note**

This post has been amended in accordance with the suggestions given below.

**Surjectivity**

Let $r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ be arbitrary. We want to find a $(x_{0},y_{0}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $g(x_{0},y_{0})=r$. Consider $x_{0}=\sqrt{r},y_{0}=0$ both of which are in $\mathbb{R}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
g(\sqrt{r},0)&=\left(\sqrt{r}\right)^{2}+0^{2} \\
&=r
\end{align*}
Since $r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ was arbitrary, it follows that $g:\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{+}$, $g(x,y)=x^{2}+y^{2}$ is surjective.

**Continuity**. Let $\epsilon >0$. Let $x_{0},y_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be arbitrary. Then $|x^{2}-x_{0}^{2}|< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ when $|x-x_{0}| < \delta$ and $|y^{2}-y_{0}^{2}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ when $|y-y_{0}| < \delta$. Thus we have:
\begin{align*}
|g(x,y)-g(x_{0},y_{0})| &=|x^{2}+y^{2}-(x_{0}^{2}+y_{0}^{2})| \\
&=|(x^{2}-x_{0}^{2})+(y^{2}-y_{0}^{2})| \\
&\leq |x^{2}-x_{0}^{2}| +|y^{2}-y_{0}^{2}| \\
&\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
&=\epsilon
\end{align*}
as $(x,y) \to (x_{0},y_{0})$. Therefore, $g$ is continuous.

Comment: How can you find $(x,y)$ such that $x^2 + y^2 < 0$?

Comment: $g$ as written is not surjective.

Comment: Argh.. a typo. Thanks @LiuGang for spotting it!

Comment: and @Omnomnomnom as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method suffices, but is a bit overly elaborate.  An easier method is as follows:

> For any $r \in \Bbb R^+: g(\sqrt{r},0) = r$.